# Configuração de zoom e drag em area SVG

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

Estou tentando fazer um sistema cria um gráfico de uma função matemática, e estou lhe desenvolvendo em `svg`. Porém estou encontrando algumas dificuldades, a primeira delas é a falta de automação, pois como sabemos, um um gráficos destes é infinito, e não consigo imaginar um jeito de realizar esta façanha. Queria algo apenas semelhante ao que acontece no [exemplo do Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=x%5E2+%2B+x+-2&oq=x%5E2+%2B+x+-2&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57.4524j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). Nele podemos perceber que algo arrastarmos ou darmos um zoom, os valores numéricos de adequam. No meu caso estou fazendo os números manualmente. Se alguém tiver alguma dica, por favor, me avise.

Meu exemplo está [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/by7ouL9o/)

Resumo do que eu estou necessitando, que ao dar zoom ou arrastar os números se adequem e que as espessuras das linhas continuam as mesma, porém em relação a "infinidade" presente no gráfico, se não puder ser feita pode ser colocado uma espécie de limitação.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema semelhante com um projeto de jogo.. acabei desenvolvendo uma simples biblioteca usando Canvas.

Documentação: 'tosca': http://200.98.200.219/morfeus/morfeus02.00_doc/

Script: http://200.98.200.219/morfeus/morfeus02.00.js

creio que com poucas alterações no código resolveria seu problema.